# Check if the function is homeomorphism.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If f be a bijective continuous function on any interval of real numbers, then is f always homeomorphism?
I am asking here for any interval of reals.

Comment: I am telling also about any interval, on which f is continuous bijection.

Comment: You can extend argument in the post above to function $f$ with any intervals as domain/codomain.

Comment: So also on open interval